# Integrate Selenium, Maven, TestNG, Zephyr with JIRA to update test cases

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, testng, jira-zephyr

I have to execute pom.xml using Jenkins and have to update test cases on Zephyr with JIRA.

I have installed zephyr with JIRA management plugin in Jenkins and have added post build action to push the result to Zephyr with JIRA.

Can anyone please help with the steps to be followed.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: I want to have list of comprehensive steps to be followed to update the test cases with their status on Zephyr after executing from Jenkins.